# change state when clicked outside of select input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, select, next.js

i have a project with nextjs.in my project i have form component.in this component i have a select component.when my select input be opened i show this message => Select is opened and when my select input be close i show this =>Select is closed.my problem is when my select open and i clecked in outside of select my state not updated.(i want when select open my isOpen state be true and when select close my isOpen state be false)

this is my Form component

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Select from "./Select";

const Form = props => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const onClickHandler = () => {
        setIsOpen(state => !state);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <Select isOpen={isOpen} name='select' id='select' onClick={onClickHandler}>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </Select>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};


export default Form;
```

this is my Select component

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Select = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.isOpen ?
                <div>Select is Opened</div> : <div>Select is closed</div>
            }
            <select onClick={props.onClick} name={props.name} id={props.id}>
                {props.children}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

Select.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.string,
    isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    children: PropTypes.node
};

export default Select;
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you Can Use `onBlur` event for handle this action :)
onBlur called function when click outside!